# NSIS file downloader

Tags: download, nsis

I need NSIS script witch  download file from the internet and execute it.
I've read many examples but I still don't understand how to do it. For example

```
NSISdl::download http://www.domain.com/file localfile.exe 
    Pop $R0 ;Get the return value 
      StrCmp $R0 "success" +3 
      MessageBox MB_OK "Download Failed: $R0" 
      Quit
```

$R0 contains information about installation process ("cancel" or "success"). But I don't understand what the "localfile.exe" is?
In what part of program I need write this code(section or function)?

Comment: Both sections and function contain code (and plugin calls), only installer attributes are specified outside sections/functions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

localfile.exe is the path on the local system where you want to save the content you are downloading:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
Section
NSISdl::download "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png" "$pluginsdir\image.png"
Pop $0
${If} $0 == "success"
    ExecShell "" '"$pluginsdir\image.png"' ;Open image in default application
${Else}
    MessageBox mb_iconstop "Error: $0" ;Show cancel/error message
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```